# xslt: match partial attribute name

Tags: xml, xslt

any xslt version should do.

assuming attributes like that :

```
<tag attr-something="1" attr-something-else="1" attr-something-more="1" attr-different="1" attr-thing="1">
```

what's the simplest way to match all attributes whose names start with *attr-something* ?

this matches one specific attribute :

```
<xsl:template match="@attr-something"/>
```

this matches a hardcoded list of attributes :

```
<xsl:template match="@attr-something|@attr-something-else"/>
```

this matches all nodes that contain attribute[s] that start with the required string :

```
<xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(@*), 'attr-something')]"/>
```

but how to match attributes themselves ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match *attributes* by a partial name you can use:

```
<xsl:template match="@*[starts-with(name(), 'attr-something')]"> ...
```