# XSL partial match on Name

Tags: xslt, sharepoint-2010

Using a single xsl template, how can one perform a partial match on a `@Name` field?

Now, I am working with a [custom Sharepoint `fldtypes.xsl` file](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/424763/Zen-and-the-art-of-XSLT-rendering-fields-SharePoin).

There is a [very nice answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14057312/how-to-match-this-or-that-in-an-xsl-template) about how to match on multiple names, but I want to match *any* field that has "phone" in the name - such as:

- Primary Phone
- Secondary Phone
- Alt phone
- phone
- Phone
- Cell phone
  *(etc....)*

Here is my current template, which works for exact matches:

```
<!-- Turn Phone number fields into callto links-->
<xsl:template match="FieldRef[contains('|phone|Phone|', concat('|',@Name,'|') )]" mode="Text_body">
    <xsl:param name="thisNode" select="."/>
    <xsl:variable name="currentValue" select="$thisNode/@*[name()=current()/@Name]" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$currentValue=''">
            <span></span>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <a href="callto:{$currentValue}" class="calltolink" target=""><xsl:value-of select="$currentValue" /></a>
        </xsl:otherwise>            
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Could you post an example of the XML input?

Comment: No, I can't.  It is picking up from *any* sharepoint page.  But I'll tag my post with `sharepoint` and explain.  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/424763/Zen-and-the-art-of-XSLT-rendering-fields-SharePoin

Comment: If you apply a stylesheet with (only) [the *identity transform* template](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform#Using_XSLT), you will see your input.

Comment: I don't really want to match on `*`.

Comment: What's the connection? I was explaining how you can see what your XML input looks like.

Comment: Sorry.  Well, what I can say is that I am matching on the `field name` and not the `display name` of a sharepoint list.

Comment: Describing your code instead of showing it is not helpful towards getting useful answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am only guessing here (since you won't show us your input) that you want to match:

```
<xsl:template match="FieldRef[contains(@Name, 'Phone') or contains(@Name, 'phone')]">
```

Comment: Thanks, but that does the same thing as my own code.  This link is closer if I can figure out how to adapt it to work with `FieldRef`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24456653/xslt-match-partial-attribute-name

Comment: @BGM "*that does the same thing as my own code.*" No, it doesn't.

Comment: Sorry again!  I'll try it.

Comment: That was it!  Thank you!  Only I used a `|` instead of 'or' but I guess that doesn't matter.

Comment: @BGM Well, [look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25407504/what-is-the-difference-between-or-and-when-programming-in-xslt/25407704#25407704), but of course, your original code does not seem to use `|` as an operator really. +1, by the way.

Comment: Nice link!  Thanks again!